# How do I repair the rotted wood in the exterior of my house?

Tags: wood, house

I am planning to hire a professional to repair the wood that rotted that is shown at the center of the photo below. What kind of a professional or a trade should I hire? Thanks in advance.

[image]

Added on Aug 10, 2022 -- a photo of the roof and gutter that are directly above the rotted wood.

[image]

Comment: General contractor, or roofing guy, your gutter needs fixing anyway

Comment: The wood that rotted (near the center of my photo) is no where close to the roof or a gutter.

Comment: But the source of rot comes from leaking roof/gutter, and it is right next to gutter, indicating the gutter is not doing its work.

Comment: To me it looks like improper siding flashing/installation at that corner.  Why is there a horizontal strip unprotected by siding at the join between the floors? Perhaps the corner piece is actually channeling water to that bottom corner? A siding person should be able to figure it out, fix it and make modifications to prevent it recurring.

Comment: Is there a bathroom or other potential source of leaks above this rotten piece of wood? Is the wood aesthetic or structural?

Comment: General contractor, because this has probably got structural implications. Siding or roofing guys generally have no clue about structure.

Comment: I agree with @Armand.  What is the point of vinyl siding if they are going to leave wood exposed like that?

Comment: Sometimes, @Armand, wood is used as siding! Shocking, I know, but there hasn't always been vinyl or aluminum siding to be used. Properly maintained, wood can be an excellent siding material. I do see signs of flashing above this trim strip, too, so someone did try to do the right thing. I'd agree with the suggestion of having a GC take a look at it, as there may be structural damage supporting the overhang. A siding contractor may "look the other way" or risk loosing the job, and not get the structural issues properly fixed.

Comment: @FreeMan You're right of course in general about wood and the GC would be the right person to go where the inspection leads rather than being siloed by specialty.  I'm dealing now with an old shed roof edge with similar damage and finding some serious mis-installed drip edge issues :)

Comment: Thanks everyone for your comments. I added a 2nd photo to show the roof and gutter that are directly above the affected area. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for the second photo of the gutter . We were looking for the source of access water that damaged that wood. When was it last time you cleaned that gutter, to prevent overflow.

Comment: We did not clean the gutter for the last 15 years. I don't know if the water overflows since this is an out-of-state property that we are renting out.

Comment: Thanks for the 2nd photo! The wood visible just under the roof edge seems weathered and perhaps warped/damaged. I think it would benefit you to have someone with knowledge inspect the whole roof/siding of the house to identify other damage or issues perhaps not as easily visible as the damage you posted about.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all of the comments on my question. I'd like to give an update -- we hired a general contractor to replace the rotted wood with primed engineered lumber for about $2,500. We plan to hire a painter soon to paint the new lumber.

[image: A photo showing what the trim looks like after the repair]